# Using a Maven build in Spring to talk to Elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, elasticsearch

I am a new developer and I've run into a problem which should have a simple answer but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm working on a project that is using Spring Tool Suit and Maven. All I want to do is output a string to an Elasticsearch URL (I have the URL). Previously I've worked with printing to and reading from a Kafka queue using spring so I believe this should have a similar answer (1-3 dependencies I'd add to the pom.xml file for Maven, a config class/annotation, and a "sender" class/annotation). All that would be left then is to add the call.

Any help is appreciated be it the code, how I would have figured this out on my own or otherwise.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you are relying too much on frameworks, IDEs and tools and lacking basic understanding about REST APIs. Elasticsearch URLs are REST APIs, so you can use any library capable of making http calls. Having said that, some libraries that came to my mind are:

1. JDK HttpUrlConnection
   (https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/). This is pretty raw deal.
2. Spring restTemplate (http://www.baeldung.com/rest-template)
3. Spring data elasticsearch
   (http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-elasticsearch-tutorial). But I
   would recommend against this unless you are familiar with Spring
   "data repositories".